# Visual Studio default Auto Complete to use System Type Name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, types, intellisense, keyword

Strange question but my boss is a touch old school and has insisted in our coding standards that we do not use C# shorthands for system types, he likes us to use the full system name. He likes things to be verbose and I happily comply with the standard.

However, something which after several months has started to grate on me is the fact that visual studio does not like to comply with the standard when completing code. So if I type:

```
KeyValuePair<Int32, Object> MyValue = new
```

Visual studio will finish the rest with:

```
KeyValuePair<int,object>
```

This is even worse when implementing an interface or abstract class.

This is a minor inconveniance but one none the less and I was wondering whether in the plethora of VS options there was one to force using the full System type names.

I believe that this can be solved use something like Re-Sharper but unfortunately there's no way I'm getting a license.

**EDIT**

Yes he despises the use of the var keyword. I should have stated his actual reasoning, it's because we mostly develop in C# but there is a high probability of needing to write in C and objective C so he does not want us to become too reliant upon CLR shorthands and he also says it would cause less pain when porting code which to a degree makes sense to me. His main aim with this is to avoid type mis matches with types such as Int16, Int32 & Int64 but as we are following a standard he prefers String over string. In all fairness, he is a very good coder if not a touch old school but his knowledge of things under the hood is vastly greater than mine and 90% of devs that I know, coming from a gaming background I guess makes you appreciate the finer points a touch more.  I've always been spoilt with a nice managed .NET framework.

Many Thanks

Paul

Comment: Is he "against" using `var` as well? If so, using `var myValue = new KeyValuePair<Int32, Object>();` means you only have to type it once.

Comment: At least he allows `using System;` right? Everyone here is so negative!

Comment: Interestingly, the only thing that's actually *unique* to the CLR is the `Int32`-style names. C definitely calls that an `int`. That's precisely what the "shorthand" was designed for: people coming from other C-style languages.

Comment: Yes we can use System ;) . I was actually going to put in the original post - "he likes us to use the full system name (minus the namespace)"

Comment: Your boss is a fool. His reasoning about porting to other languages is stupid and backwards. The porting would be easier if he used keywords common to all the languages he's interested in. Also, porting to another language is wasteful anyway. Get a better boss.

Comment: OK, I'm not doubting your knowledge of the subject, I'm sure you make a highly valid point about the porting but sadly that doesn't really answer my question, I only included the detail of why I was asking the question because I knew I would have a vast amount of questions of why on earth I was asking such an obscure question. Maybe we should have a corporate Coup ;).

Comment: I think people are making ad-hominem attacks against your boss because there's no actual way to solve this problem. I'd love to be proven wrong, but I don't think it's going to happen using only the tools that come with Visual Studio. You could use snippets, but honestly I'd rather just type the code myself. IntelliSense makes this easy enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My research indicates this is not possible.  Maybe in a future version of Visual Studio...